# How to add multiple values in Ansible template Variables - SSIS config file

Tags: ansible, ansible-template, ansible-awx

I am looking for the solution of the below:
I have SSIS package which has few configurations. I need them all to be defined in ansible template job. For single call I am using variable:
`{ "ssis_execute_packagepath": "X:\\path\\to\\package\\package.dtsx", "ssis_execute_configpath": "X:\\path\\to\\config\\file\\configfile.dtsConfig" }`

How can I call in the ansible template all configfile, configfile1 and configfile2 to run them in parallel?